# mongodb add item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

```
            await Cart.update(
              { $elemMatch: { user_id: decoded._id } },
              {
                $addToSet: {
                  "cart.&.items": {
                    product_id: req.query.product_id,
                    quantity: 1,
                  },
                },
              }
            );
```

[image]
**My goal is to add elements to the array of items in the cart.**

Comment: Please edit your question by replacing the screenshot with text (copy & paste). Not only do links die, but it poses problems for the visually impaired.

Answer (score 1):

There's no syntax with `&` sign. MongoDB offers `$` as a positional operator which allows you to modify existing item but you don't needed since you just want to append a new object to an array, try:

```
{
    $addToSet: {
        "cart.items": {
            product_id: req.query.product_id,
            quantity: 1,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to use the elemMatch structure? @mickl

Comment: @Anonim just use `{ user_id: decoded._id }`, `$elemMatch` is for querying the array

Comment: It finds but did not add. Why not add :(

Comment: The syntax looks correct https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#examples

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did it by changing the method you did a little. You can look at the answers I added.

Comment: @Anonim so you were using `$addToSet` but same value was already there?

Comment: There wasn't the same value in the array. I was using it to add a different value. I tried both methods. I printed the errors and analyzed them.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Cart.updateMany(
              { user_id: decoded._id },
              {
                $push: {
                  "cart.items": {
                    product_id: req.query.product_id,
                    quantity: 1,
                  },
                },
              }
            )
```

I finally found the right method through trial and error.